# How to keep an email log of users who accessed a certain spreadsheet with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Many times I've faced the need to keep a log from every user who accessed a certain spreadsheet. But I needed to export this information to store it in a separated spreadsheet.
The following simple script does exactly that. It is triggered by an installable "on Open" trigger.
Just go to *Edit > All your triggers* in the menu bar and create a new trigger to set it up.

```
function sheetUserLog() {

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); //Gets users email.
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc1234567'); // Gets the target spreadsheet by its ID. Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side. It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('openings_log'); //Gets the target sheet.
  var lr = ts.getLastRow() + 1; // Gets the first empty row at the bottom of the range.

  // Prints user's email and opening timestamp.
  ts.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(email);
  ts.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(new Date());

}
```

Comment: Please can you explain what your quesition is? It's not obvious from the question as it stands.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question was asked.

Comment: The purpose of this question was to show an issue that I had and to present the solution that I arrived to. How could I rephrase the question to make it more useful to all? Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The `openById(id)` method opens the spreadsheet with the given ID. A spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0
```

is `abc1234567`.

[openById(id) method oficial explanation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))